# Refresh outlook inbox via python script

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to read emails from the outlook  by means of win32com.
It's working well only if the email are displayed in outlook desktop application. But it could de something in the server, which could not been seen without manual outlook inbox refreshing. Is this any chance to update the outlook via  command and get the latest emails from the server?

Currient code:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts;
inbox = outlook.Folders(accounts[0].DeliveryStore.DisplayName).Folders('Inbox')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Namespace.SendAndReceive` - keep in mind that it is asynchronous, so you won't see the changes immediately.

Comment: Is there any chance to let python wait for the folder to be updated? Or to get the last date the folder has been updated?

Comment: Use `Namespace.SyncObjects` collection to retrieve the very first `SyncObject` (All Accounts). Wait for the `SyncObject.SyncEnd` event to fire.